# SQL Find & Replace part of a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find certain text "catid=18" in a string, where each string is different except for this.
I've used this query below before, except it only seems to work if you know the entire string.

```
update TABLE_NAME
set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, 'findthis', 'replacewiththis');
```

Comment: You want to find a string and use replace? Could you please give more info.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is what you want. But it will return `1` if `catid=any_num` is found and `0` if not:

```
select 'some_text catid=18 some_text' REGEXP 'catid=[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need:

```
update TABLE_NAME
set FIELD_NAME = 'goodvalue'
WHERE FIELD_NAME = 'badvalue';
```

Comment: To be more specific, here's one of the urls. Im trying to replace the "catid=51" with catid="7". Each url is different:

index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=149:multiple-objectives-when-deciding-to-sell-a-medical-practice&amp;catid=51:articles&amp;Itemid=114

Comment: They all exist within the same table and field name, if that helps

Comment: Now you are talking about urls. Please show us some real data from real tables instead of your meta-babble.